# Why does the ul element show when input is clicked?

Tags: html, jquery, css, absolute

For some reason the `ul` gets `display: none`, and is not displayed even when the impute element is clicked.
This is the html
When this is clicked:

```
 <input class="input country" type="text"/>
```

This html should show (but it doesn't):

```
 <ul id='country-list'>
                <li id="US">United States</li>
 </ul>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
function handleCountries() {
    $('#country-list').hide();
    $('#country').click(function () {
        $("#country-list").show();
    });
};

function handleTestOut() {
    handleCountries()
};

$(handleTestOut)
```

This is the html:

```
 <div class="container">
            <input class="input country" type="text"/>
            <ul id='country-list'>
                <li id="US">United States</li>
            </ul>
            <button>explore</button>
        </div>
```

This is some css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

.input {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
  height: 200px;
  width: 18%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 20px
}
```

[Here is the full code](https://repl.it/@EliReiner/NavyblueFearlessPayware)

Edit: I removed the invalid html, but am getting the same results

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: `</ul id='country-list'>` isn’t valid HTML.

Comment: Where in your code is `handleCountries` called? (I see it in repl.it, but you should add it into this question.

Comment: @Rojo Inside `handleTestOut`. It’s here in the question.

Comment: @user4642212 sorry, didn't see that. Also, I've never seen a function run using jquery. Are you sure that works? Could you point me to a website where you saw running a function using jQuery? Anyway, I don't see why you would jQuery to run a function instead of plain JavaScript. I'd assume plain Javascript in a bit faster.

Comment: @Rojo It’s the `$(function(){` … `})` pattern which is a shorthand of `$(document).ready(function(){` … `})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hide it with:  `$('#country-list').hide();`

And what is with this functions calling each other?

You are using jQuery to call `handleTestOut` function in witch you call `handleCountries` function. It does not make much sense.

You will get absolutely same result if you just leave it out of functions:

But your main problem was you don't have `#country` id you have `.country` CSS class for click calling (or use `input.country` or `.input` class, or all of it `input.country.input`):

```js
$('#country-list').hide();

$('.country').click(function() {
  $("#country-list").show();
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #1b4639;
  background: #cbe2e4;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

.input {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
  height: 200px;
  width: 18%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <div class="container">
      <input class="input country" type="text" />
      <ul id='country-list'>
        <li id="US">United States</li>
        <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
        <li id="AX">Åland Islands</li>
        <li id="AL">Albania</li>
        <li id="DZ">Algeria</li>
        <li id="AS">American Samoa</li>
        <li id="AD">Andorra</li>
        <li id="AO">Angola</li>
        <li id="AI">Anguilla</li>
        <li id="AQ">Antarctica</li>
        <li id="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</li>
        <li id="AR">Argentina</li>
        <li id="AM">Armenia</li>
        <li id="AW">Aruba</li>
        <li id="AU">Australia</li>
        <li id="AT">Austria</li>
        <li id="AZ">Azerbaijan</li>
        <li id="BS">Bahamas</li>
        <li id="BH">Bahrain</li>
        <li id="BD">Bangladesh</li>
        <li id="BB">Barbados</li>
        <li id="BY">Belarus</li>
        <li id="BE">Belgium</li>
        <li id="BZ">Belize</li>
        <li id="BJ">Benin</li>
        <li id="BM">Bermuda</li>
        <li id="BT">Bhutan</li>
        <li id="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</li>
        <li id="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</li>
        <li id="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</li>
      </ul>
      <button>explore</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```